# Разница между Cookies и сессиями

Tags: php, cookie, сессия

Здравствуйте, все никак не могу понять разницы между куки и сеансом. Насколько мне известно, если в броузере отключен прием кук, то авторизацию и регистрацию пользователь не пройдет, исходя из этих соображений для регистрации я делаю на `session_start`, но если я в броузере выключаю куки, то все ровно не заходит.

Как работать с куки и сессиями? В каждом файле надо делать проверку на существование сессии, для того, чтобы если их нет, то человек не смог зайти на эту страницу? Еще я замечал на некоторых сайтах, что в броузерной строке по мимо адреса еще есть `session_name` и `session_id`. Как это делается и для чего?

Пожалуйста, объяснить мне простыми словами, а не заученными терминами, как и с чем работать? Что и для чего надо? Можно с примерами в которых будет пояснение, спасибо.

Comment: При работе с сессий куки нужны только для сохранения PHPSESSID в ппеделах сеанса. Т.е. при отключенных куках все равно ничего хорошего не выйдет, но в сессии можно (но не нужно) хранить большие объемы данных, к тому же они недоступны юзеру для изменения напрямую.

Answer (score 18):

Это разные явления.

**Cookie** — это просто пара имя-значение, которую (точнее, которые) сервер может оставить у клиента (браузера). Наглядно:

1. Приходит клиент, спрашивает у сервера страницу.
2. Сервер в заголовках ответе может установить cookies. Например, выдав два заголовка: `Set-Cookie: foo=123` и `Set-Cookie: bar=baz` — по-русски — «запомни, foo — 123, а bar — baz».
3. При следующем обращении клиент, если он решил запомнить, говорит серверу «Cookie: bar=baz; foo=123».

Упрощенно, не затрагивая тонкости — все, вот все, что представляют собой cookies.

**Сессии** — более эфемерное понятие, которое не привязано к какой-то конкретной реальной технологии. Это просто некая методика, которая позволяет отличить одного клиента от другого, и, как правило, где-то хранить связанные с каждым клиентом данные.

Как правило, сессии реализуются используя cookies и идентификаторы сессий. Т.е. сервер со своей стороны создает уникальный идентификатор, например, «1a2b3c» (**`session_id`** про который вы справшивали), а клиента просит его запомнить. Обычно — при помощи cookies, говоря что-то в духе `Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=1a2b3c` (где «`PHPSESSID`» — **имя сессии**, обычно, оно только одно, вести параллельно несколько сессий нужно редко). Со своей стороны сервер где-то (зависит от реализации, иногда это файл, например, `/tmp/1a2b3c`, иногда запись в БД, иногда еще что-то) хранит различные данные, которые ему приказано связывать с этой сессией. Например, имя пользователя.

PHP'шные сессии использова**ли** не только cookies, но и аргументы в адресной строке. Т.е. перед отдачей страницы пользователю «переписывали» все ссылки в ней, добавляя свое «?PHPSESSID=1a2b3c». И клиент вместо «`/forum.php`» шел на «`/forum.php?PHPSESSID=1a2b3c`». Таким образом сервер получал идентификатор сессии и все работало.
Сейчас PHP *по умолчанию* такого [не делает](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid) — у этого метода есть куча своих недостатков. Хотите включить — напишите `ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', true);`, но нужно понимать связанные риски.

Еще можно хранить идентификаторы сессий в других местах. Например, Local Shared Objects («флэшевские cookie»), использовать возможности хранилищ HTML5, и еще ряде менее тривиальных мест, но PHP этого «из коробки» не умеет.

Соответственно, раз и cookies и поддержка `use_trans_sid` (перезаписи адресов) отключены, то PHP не может нигде оставить у клиента «метку». И сессии, по сути, не работают. Это, в общем-то, не должно быть проблемой — если клиенту надо — он включит cookies.

**Еще** момент. Сами по себе сессии не дают авторизации — это только хранилище. Авторизацию делаете Вы сами (или фреймворк, которым Вы воспользовались). Вы пользуетесь тем, что данные, связанные с сессией (в типичной PHP'шной реализации) хранятся на сервере, и клиент их там подменить не может.

Соответственно, когда клиент аутентифицируется — в сессии сохраняется кто он. Обратно — если у нас в сессии записано кто он — можно этому верить. Вся дальнейшая логика — пускать ли клиента, давать ли ему какие-то возможности и т.д. — на Вас.

> Как работать с куки и сессиями? В каждом файле надо делать проверку на существование сессии, для того чтобы если их нет то человек не смог зайти на эту страницу?

Зависит от того, что Вы хотите, и от того, как Вы все строите. Если к этой странице должен быть доступ только у авторизованных пользователей — да, как вариант, так.

Иногда все запросы пропускают через один скрипт-«диспетчер». Иногда во все скрипты в начало вставляют include, которое инициализирует общую для всего сайта логику (сессии, авторизация).

Answer (score 4):

Сессия создается на сервере, а куки хранятся у пользователя на компьютере.
Протокол HTTP не может определять связь между двумя запросами одного и того же пользователя. Для этого мы создаем переменные сессии. Важно понимать, что эти переменные сохраняются даже после завершения выполнения php сценария.

Идентификатор сессии автомаически сохраняется в браузере пользователя в виде cookie, а если браузер cookie не поддерживает - идентификатор добавляется автоматически к адресу страницы и всем ссылкам на ней. Это значит, что при обновлении страницы браузер сам отправит на сервер идентификатор сессии, независимо от действий пользователя.

Answer (score 1):

Как в таком случае работать: перенаправлять на главную и указывать, что куки по-хорошему бы надо включить.
session_name задает имя сессии на случай, если надо разделить сессии в пределах одного домена. Хотя это лучше не делать через адресную строку, а использовать [в коде](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php).