# Безопасность в SESSION PHP и идентификация пользователя

Tags: php, сессия, регистрация

Дайте совет.
У меня форма регистрации валидируется JS, после успешной валидации аякс запросом пользователь добавляется в БД и должна открыться страница на которую имеет доступ только этот пользователь. Я в файле обработчике добавляю в сессию маил пользователя и проверку если существует такая сессия то происходит переадресация.

Мне правда кажется это какой то колхоз и пострадает безопасность, подскажите какие действия необходимо проделать сразу после регистрации чтобы идентифицировать пользователя.

PS при авторизации я в сессию добавляю ID юзера из БД а при регистрации не получается.

Comment: «а при регистрации не получается» — а должно получаться, непонятно в чём проблемы возникли

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почти все среднестатические веб-приложение в наше время, имеют авторизацию и регистрацию такого типа. Что именно вы думаете будет небезопасно? Сессия создаётся на сервере, взаимодетвие между клиентом и сервером у вас идёт по **HTTPS**(предположительно, если это не так, то вам срочно нужно покупать TSL сертификат, ибо это одна из главных дыр в безопасном э). Взаимодействуя с сервером по средствам `Ajax` Сервер воспринимает ваш `Ajax` Клиент как обычный браузер клиент. То есть, безопасность вашего приложения, полностью зависит от вас, и именно в той схеме о которой вы рассказали, дыр по идее быть не должно. Советую вам больше сконцентрироваться на готовности к `DDoS`, `CSRF`, `XSS`. И купите `TSL` Сертификат. И да, скорее всего добавить `ID` Пользовался при регистрации у вас не получаеться потому что на момент когда вы заносите `ID` В сессию, он ещё не создана в базе данных, ну это конечно требует уточнений.

Comment: 1) Если честно я ничего не понял, какой такой "тип"? на AJAX? 95% не использует ajax при регистрации. 2) В середине текста - вода. 3) Может уязвимости в конкретном примере нет, НО когда речь идет о регистрации/авторизации и т.п. 99% проектов сессии не юзает, все делают по другой схеме. 4) Концовка вроде норм, хотя никто не мешает автору получать ID нового пользователя и записывать его в сессию.

Comment: Я не хочу разводить здесь ликбез по поводу моего ответа, это не то сообщество. Заглянув в ваш ответ, я увидел что речь идёт о `Cookie` Этого мне хватило чтобы понять что ваше понимание сессий немного размыто. Не знаю о какой-такой схеме идёт речь, но даже ларавель со свей регистрацией из коробки, использует куки/сессии. Что-то вы путаете. :)

Comment: Размыто? да что там размывать? Не годно стрелки на других перепихивать, Как вы собираетесь на сессиях реализовать "Запомнить меня"? Или каждый раз человеку нужно будет перезаходить на сайт? думаю на текущем сайте как и на прочих других вы таким делом не занимаетесь. Или вы не знаете как легко прервать сессию? P.S. Не надо сомневаться в моих знаниях)

Comment: Ну вот этими вопросами, вы доказываете свои размытые знания о сессиях. Вот вам немного о том что такое сессии, тут вы сразу поймёте что это те-же куки, а точнее обертка над куками чтобы нам было удобнее работать.  http://php.net/manual/ru/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: :О То что сессии используют куки - не значит что это обертка, омг. Сессия это целая система, генерирования ключа, хранение и поддержание.  Вы путаете 2 понятия: кука - это то что хранится у клиента, сессия это уже целый механизм, просто для идентификации юзает куку. Там куча операций происходит, но смысл один - механизм сессий остается неизменным. Для авторизации такой механизм не используется. Как пример: вы не можете 2ум разным клиентам сделать разное время существование сессии, всегда будет одно. Собсна и реализовать функционал авторизации на сессиях невозможно из-за механизма работы.

Comment: Извините, но вы не правы. :) Сессии это гораздо более лучший и безопасный способ авторизации и регистрации пользователя, они напрямую связаны с куками, удалит их можно удалив куку phpsessionid, и время жизни задать проще простого. Советую вам в своих проектах использовать именно сессии, это один из лучших ответов, ибо кидать большую статью, смысла нет. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/90293/266177

Comment: Еще раз: вы не можете используя сессии задать разное время жизни, одному пользователю нужно "Запомнится" на сайте, другому надо закрыть браузер и чтобы сайт о нем забыл. Второй момент можно сказать реализован в сессиях по дефолту, а реализовать первый - невозможно. А если у вас проще простого - то тыкните мне пальцем в функцию где КОНКРЕТНО кому-то я могу задать время жизни.

Comment: Как я и сказал, задав время жизни куки в которой храниться сессия, мы можем задать время жизни сессии, функция которая нам поможет — http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-set-cookie-params.php, также возможна настройка из `php.ini`. Как я и сказал, ваше понимание сессий, довольно размыто.

Comment: :D Так это для всех, вы ВСЕМ зададите это время, а конкретному как? Зададите вы там 10 часов, у всех будет 10 часов, вне зависимости от действий ;) При этом я хочу подчеркнуть что там задается настройка куков, кука может и вечность хранится но при очередно вызове session_start() будут удалены неактуальные куки и будет несоответствие и сессия разорвется. Вы пытаетесь уже крутиться на ходу, я уже вижу что функционала "Запомнить" на вашем сайте нет и все обходится обычными сессиями. Зачем вы мне тогда что-то предъявляете?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76798/discussion-between---and-manitikyl).

Comment: спасибо. я понял что в целом сессия веоятно подходит, единственный вопрос остался это как при нажатии кнопки регистрация получить в сессию ID если на той же кнопке пользователь только что попадает в бд и должно произойти перенаправление на его аккаунт? Можно ли в этом случае вообще в сессию закладывать маил указанный при регистрации (и использовать такую конструкцию (if($_SESSION['mail']){ require '/view/todo_list.php; }) или все таки лучше использовать ID из бд?

Comment: @Чайник вам просто надо после создания новой записи с `ID`, получить этот `ID` по полю `email`  например, и занести в сессию. 
Если ответ вас удовлитворяет, пометьте его соответственно.

Comment: `if($_POST['valid']){//регистрация пользователя в бд
 session_start();
 $reg = new auth(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
 
 $reg->registration($_POST['name'], $_POST['mail'], $_POST['pass']);//добавляю пользователя в бд
 
 $reg->get_id($_POST['mail']); // пытаюсь сразу получить его ID но ничего не выходит почему то`

Comment: немогу понять как это реализовать, когда пользователь добавляется ниже строчкой пытаюсь получить ID но почему то не получаю, видимо надо чтобы страница перезагрузилась

Comment: Нет, это вовсе не нужно, если у вас добавилась запись в БД вы можете получить, но что-то не выходит, может проблема ы функции get_id?

Comment: нет get_id работает при авторизации. то есть если я авторизируюсь идет запрос в БД и в сессию попадает ID все нормально. А вот при регистрации в базе данных запись появляется а вот get_id не срабатывает

Comment: УРА!!! этот вопрос решил, при регистрации отправлялся аякс запрос в файл обработчик где происходило добавление пользователя в БД, я сделал вложенный аякс запрос в котором как раз и доставал эти данные. Спасибо за участие, главный вопрос про сессии решен собственно=)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно на похожий вопрос я когда-то давал ответ, [загляните сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/703962/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85/704066#704066). Если это не то, то дайте знать подробнее в чем суть вопроса.