# Какая разница между сеансом и сессиями? Это одно и тоже?

Tags: php, сессия

Какая разница между сеансом и сессиями? Это одно и тоже?
Перечитал много всего и немного запутался.
Здесь написано (https://depositfiles.od.ua/php/13.php скрин - http://prntscr.com/oo68rp ), 
что это приход пользователя на сайт, но приход пользователя на сайт и авторизация на сайте это разные вещи.
Сессия это скорее всего с момента авторизации пользователя на сайте ведь сессия стартует функцией session_start ().
Но если ты просто зашел на сайт и не авторизовался это сеанс?
Как правильно это понять?
Пролейте кто нибудь свет на данный момент.
Спасибо за Ваши ответы)

Comment: "Сеанс представляет собой уникальное подключение компьютера к серверу. Сервер использует сеансы, помимо прочего, для отслеживания состояния вашей работы. Сервер создает сеансы по мере необходимости."  https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-74938c0d-9652-4f10-b87c-1a7682540dfb#__toc241372470

Comment: Так вот, "Сервер создает сеансы по мере необходимости" - это те самые сессии в PHP.

Comment: Когда юзер заходит на сайт открывается общая сессия. Это тот момент когда Сервер и Браузер соглашаются о передаче данных.

Comment: Так что в целом вы правы, это можно сказать одно и то же если верить microsoft.

Comment: Связанные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/90280/256824

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы сказал так. Сервер обрабатывает запросы от *клиентов*. В данном случае *клиент* - это программное обеспечение (обычно вэб-браузер, но может быть любая программа, формирующая запросы и обрабатывающая ответы сервера, выполняемая на любом вычислительном устройстве - компьютере, смартфоне, планшете).

Если сервер получает возможность отличать запросы, приходящих от одного и того же *клиента*, от всех остальных запросов - то это уже сессия. Как этот процесс реализуется - не принципиально, хоть через куки, хоть через дополнительные заголовки HTTP-запроса, хоть через параметры запроса. В PHP реализован стандартный механизм поддержки сессий через значение в COOKIE с помощью функций `session_start()` и `session_destroy()`.

Авторизация и аутентификация пользователей - это из другой оперы, хотя результат аутентификации сессия позволяет сохранять, и, получив запрос в рамках сессии, можно поднять данные об авторизовавшемся пользователе в этой сессии (или информацию о том, что пользователь еще не авторизовался на сервере).

В итоге получаем следующее:

1. Если сервер получает возможность определять, что некоторая группа запросов приходит от одного и того же *клиента* (браузера, мобильного приложения, etc.), - то это **сессия**.
2. В PHP существует стандартный встроенный механизм управления сессиями. Для его использования необходимо в начале обработки запроса вызвать функцию [session_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php).
3. Для завершения сессии и удаления всех сессионных данных требуется вызвать функцию [session_destroy()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.session-destroy.php). При этом следующее обращение того же *клиента* к этому же серверу, в котором будет вызвана функция session_start(), инициирует новую сессию с пустым сессионным хранилищем (если до этого пользователь был авторизован на сайте - то инициация новой сессии и / или уничтожение старой будет равноценна логауту этого пользователя).
4. Авторизовался пользователь на сайте или не авторизовался - вопрос, не имеющий отношения к определению сессии. Но инициализация новой сессии создает новое пустое сессионное хранилище, новый уникальный идентификатор сессии, и [обычно] равноценна логауту ранее авторизованного пользователя.
5. При этом, прошу учесть, логаут пользователя на сервере абсолютно не означает закрытие сессии сервера с *клиентом*. Просто в рамках этой же сессии может быть произведена повторная авторизация того же или другого пользователя, и обычно так и происходит. Проверяется это просто:

   - откройте в браузере консоль, убедитесь, что видите запросы браузера к серверу
   - обновите страницу в браузере, найдите и сохраните где-либо значение сессионной куки (по умолчанию ее имя в PHP равно *PHPSESSID*)
   - авторизуйтесь на сайте и сравните текущее значение сессионной куки с сохраненным
   - разлогиньтесь на сайте и снова сверьте текущее значение сесионной куки с сохраненным

Сессия может длиться долго. Очень долго. Годами. Пока на сервере и на *клиенте* хранится ее идентификатор и пока не исчерпался лимит времени ее жизни, задаваемый, например, [session_set_cookie_params()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.session-set-cookie-params.php).

Термин ***сеанс*** я бы все же использовал применительно к работе пользователя. С моей точки зрения, "сеанс работы пользователя" или "пользовательский сеанс" звучат достаточно информативно, благозвучно и непротиворечиво по отношению к ***сессии***. Хотя приходилось встречать и выражение ***пользовательская сессия*** с тем же смыслом, что и ***пользовательский сеанс***. При этом пользовательский сеанс длится с момента авторизации пользователя на сервере и до момента его логаута *по любой причине* - то ли сам вышел, то ли время с момента его последнего обращения превысило предельно допустимое и его выкинуло автоматом, то ли админ его забанил, не суть. При этом *не обязательно* логаут пользователя приводит к запуску новой сессии между *клиентом* и сервером. Реализация механизма авторизации пользователей рулит.

Зачастую люди (программисты, пользователи) "проглатывают" в выражении "пользовательская сессия" первое слово. Это приводит к путанице в терминологии и к тому, что смысл определений ***сессия*** и ***пользовательская сессия*** начинают накладываться друг на друга в сознании людей, не копавших достаточно глубоко в этом направлении.

P.S. Возможно, Вы обращали внимание на то, что запустив на компьютере 2 разных браузера Вы можете работать на одном сайте под двумя различными учетными записями. Но в одном и том же браузере работать **одновременно** под различными записями у Вас [обычно] не получается. Это результат того, что для соединения с каждым браузером вэб-сервер открывает свою уникальную и единственную сессию (если сервер в принципе эти сессии поддерживает). И в рамках одной сессии Вы не сможете одновременно работать под разными учетками. А с двух различных ***клиентов*** - браузеров - вполне себе можете.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)
То есть насколько я понял зашел на сайт это уже сессия и оно никак связано с тем была активирована PHP сессия.
Можно ли такую сессию назвать HTTP сессия?

Но в случае, когда мы просто зашли на сайт хотя это считается как сессия, но по факту сервер не может сохранять никаких данных бо файл для сессии на сервере создается только после вызова функции session start().

Comment: Я не готов угадывать смысл, который Вы вкладываете в термин "зашел на сайт". Поскольку это может быть и "открыл любую страницу сайта без авторизации на нем" и "сервер в принципе не поддерживает сессии, а я открыл на нем страничку", и "я авторизовался на сайте". Термин "HTTP-сессия" я бы не вводил, поскольку это есть просто **_сессия_**, открытая на сервере для **_клиента_** (определение **_клиента_** см. в ответе). А если на сервере не выполнилась _session_start()_ и _не реализован другой, отличный от стандартного механизм управления сессиями_ то сессии, извините, нет. Есть обработка запросов.

Comment: @testdev, галочку не забудьте поставить, чтобы вопрос-ответ не канул в небытие.

Comment: В качестве реализации _альтернативного механизма управления сессиями_ могу привести пример портала для приставок **_Ministra_** (ранее **_Stalker Middleware_**). Если как следует в нем покопаться, то можно увидеть, что в качестве идентификатора сессии используется MAC-адрес приставки, отображающей его содержимое. При этом MAC удовлетворяет всем требованиям идентификатора сессии - он _уникален_ и он _однозначно идентифицирует клиента_.

Comment: Хочу понять как работают те сессии и немного запутался.
Вы писали - Если сервер получает возможность отличать запросы, приходящих от одного и того же клиента, от всех остальных запросов - то это уже сессия. (Http://prntscr.com/ooryy7)

В ответ на комментарий вы писали
А если на сервере не выполнилась session_start() и не реализован другой, отличный от стандартного механизм управления сессиями то сессии, извините, нет. Есть обработка запросов.

Comment: http://i.uran.ru/webcab/system/files/bookspdf/rnr-7/php.pdf Глава 34. Хотя я бы порекомендовал прочитать всю книгу. Не помешает. P.S. читать удобнее на бумаге. И автору от этого польза малая.